Break circular reference in Typescript
I'm trying to declare a const with the following structure:
type Element = null | {parent: keyof typeof TREE};
const TREE = {
  'a': null,
  'b': {parent: 'a'},
} satisfies Record<string, Element>;

That gets me in trouble because of the circular reference. How to get around it and obtain the same functionality, such that TS will allow me in the future to add nodes to TREE and still check that every parent exists in the tree?

If you want to fix a circular reference you need to break the circularity. Instead of using TREE to contextually type itself, just write const TREE = {⋯} as const, and then do a check later, as shown in this playground link. The error might not be where you want it, but it will tell you what needs to be fixed.  Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Yes, this works, thanks! Only note: I have to explicitly cast (const check = TREE as Record<string, Element>;) due to compiler settings against implicit conversion in my env.

"Compiler settings"? I don't know any such compiler setting. Maybe you have some linter? Anyway, that type assertion (what you're calling a "cast") could possibly allow unsafe things (const x: X = y is stricter than const x = y as X) so you should probably fix your settings not to prefer type assertions over type annotations. I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

I would consider reporting this as a bug. Using satisfies should not have an effect on the type of TREE as far as I can see, it should be checked afterwards.

Please do not report a bug, it would be swiftly closed as a duplicate of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55189 and others. satisfies intentionally serves as a source for contextual typing

Instead of trying to declare and check TREE against itself all at once, you can break it apart into two separate pieces. First, you declare things:
type Element = null | { parent: keyof typeof TREE };
const TREE = {
  'a': null,
  'b': { parent: 'a' },
} as const;

and then you check them:
const check: Record<string, Element> = TREE; // okay

This breaks the circularity because the type of TREE does not depend on anything but the initializer. Presumably you were using the satisfies operator to give context to the TREE initializer so that it would keep track of the literal types of the parent properties, instead of inferring string. Instead of doing that, you can use a const assertion, which also preserves literal types without being circular.
Then the check const check: Record<string, Element> = TREE will compile if and only if that assignment is an acceptable one. If TREE has any properties whose type is not Element, then you'll get an error:
const TREE = {
  'a': null,
  'b': { parent: 'c' }, // <-- 'c'
} as const;
const check: Record<string, Element> = TREE; // error!
//    ~~~~~
//         Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.

That error might not be exactly where you'd like it to be, but it at least tells you what the problem is.
Playground link to code
